# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.htrace.core.Tracer$Builder

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I am trying to run a MapReduce program in Eclipse and am repeatedly getting an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.htrace.core.Tracer$Builder.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

I downloaded the .jar files from here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.htrace/htrace-hbase/3.1.0-incubating
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.htrace/htrace-hbase/4.1.0-incubating
And put them in my project folder, under a 'lib' directory, before manually adding them to the Eclipse project reference library using the menu options 'Build Path > Configure Build Path'. Yet the error persists.

Any idea how to fix it? I am brand new to Java and so would be really grateful for any insights that will get my program to run. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

In Eclipse, right click on the project. Select `Properties>Java Build Path>Add External Jars>File System`. Add any .jars in `usr/lib/hadoop` and `usr/lib/hadoop/client`.